# Ubuntu Booting Stuck. Error is 'Btrfs Loaded'

Tags: boot, ubuntu-16.04, btrfs

I am not able to bot into a ubuntu 16.04 LTS system. Attaching image. I am trying from past few days but couldn't figure out issue.

[Screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTrKK.jpg)

Comment: Reinstall from USB.

Comment: OK I'm making a few assumptions here but I think you are using a cloud image on a hypervisor. At least I experienced something similar when I was performing the setup on a Proxmox VE hypervisor. You could be running into a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-images/+bug/1573095) where the cloud image will fail to boot if a serial port is not available. I followed the steps [here](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Cloud-Init_Support) to configure a serial console and use it as a display. Adapt this to your circumstances and see if it resolves the issue for you. YMMV.